# rooViewController leaving gap at the bottom of the screen

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, simulator

Mt rootViewController (i.e the first viewcontroller) is not occupying full screen, while the other VCs do (see screenshot). In IB, they look identical. I am using iOS 6 / iOS 5.1 simulator.

My AppDelegate method looks innocent. Any suggestions?

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // hide status bar
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // allocate the root view controller
    _window.rootViewController = [[LMHomeViewController alloc] init];
    // add a navigation controller
    [LMNavigationController initSharedInstanceWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
    [_window addSubview:LMNavigationController.sharedInstance.view];
    // show the window
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the status bar in your LMHomeViewController xib file.

In your info.plist set "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES.

I think the problem is that your LMHomeViewController get "rendered with a status bar" and then you add this view to a view without a status bar, so there is a 20 px gap.

Answer (score 0):

//in appDelegate.h file

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) LMHomeViewController *homeController;

//in appDelegate.m file

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

self.homeController = [[[LMHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMHomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;